# Two-sided amsbook with custom title page

Tags: titles, amsbook

I am using `amsbook` to typeset a two-sided document and want to add a custom title page.
The problem is that it inserts the TOC right after the title page, without leaving an empty page inbetween.
The subsequent chapters then also start at "left" pages.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}
  This is the title
 \end{titlepage}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

I would expect the first page (the title page) to be followed by a blank page so that the TOC starts at the third, as is the case when replacing `amsbook` with the `book` class in the above example.

Any attempt to force an empty page, for example by inserting

```
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

before `\tableofcontents`, creates *two* empty pages and the TOC then again starts at a "left" page.

Is there any way I can make the TOC (and the subsequent chapters) to start at a "right hand" page?

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TOC starts on page 1 so is a right hand page although it is physically the second page in the sequence.  if you do

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}
  This is the title
 \end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{0}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Then it will still be page 1 but physically the third page.

Comment: may i observe that `twoside` and `openright` are the defaults.